# gap between LI's on drop down menu in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml, gaps-in-visuals

Hi I ave a drop down menu which when dropped, there is a gap between the li's. I have tried all usual methods but I cant seem to find where it is coming from!

I would paste the code but there is a bit of it so I have set up a temp directory for you to see.

http://www.actwebdesigns.com/web-design-mansfield/

Regards,

Phil

Comment: Your drop-down menu is awfully slow by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing all white space between `<li>`s:

```
<ul id="servicesSubNav">
<li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li><li><a href="#">Content Management Systems</a></li><li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
```

looks ugly in the code, but should solve it.

Comment: ha, was gonna quickly type a sarcy reply about the reasons why I doubt that would work but ha! your a genius and im an idiot! thanks!